# Restrict users access to save file in one drive only

Tags: windows

restrict users from saving files in c: drive root user folder and only save in one drive only. Also download files should only go to document folder not download folder. is there any group policy to achieve this task.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For making sure that users save their files and so on in Onedrive there is a feature called known folders

See here for more info and docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/redirect-known-folders

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-group-policy

Comment: thank so much it looks like a perfect solution. so by using this known folder feature the data wont get stored in c: ?